# What are the objects and morphisms of the category $\operatorname{Vect}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, category-theory

What are the objects and morphisms of the category $\operatorname{Vect}$?

I am trying to learn category theory, and it seems we have infinite objects in $\operatorname{Vect}$ being all of the finite dimensional vector spaces over the relevant field $\Bbb F$.

The morphisms (arrows) should be mappings from each vector space to one another. Are there infinitely many morphisms? I can't see how they would be countable if there are.

Or are classes of vector spaces and classes of morphisms put into much simpler terms?

Comment: Objects = Vector Spaces.    //   Morphisms = Linear Maps.     //    Where is the confusion?

Comment: The morphisms should just be all linear maps.

Comment: @Shalop I don't get it, there is no mathematical notation? It is just written in words?

Comment: In a category $C$, suppose we have two objects $A$ and $B$. Then there is a set Hom$_C(A,B)$, which is associated to the pair of objects $A,B$. This set Hom$_C(A,B)$ consists of all of the morphisms from $A$ into $B$. When we talk about morphisms in a given category, we are just giving a general description of all of the collective morphisms in Hom$_C(A,B)$, as $A,B$ range over all objects in $C$. For vector spaces $V$ and $W$, the set of morphisms Hom$(V,W)$ would just be all of the linear maps from $V$ to $W$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\sf Vect$ (or ${\sf Vect}_{\mathbb{F}}$) is often used to denote the category of *all* vector spaces over a base field $\mathbb{F}$, not just the smaller category of finite-dimensional ones.

Either way, for any vector spaces $\mathbb{V}, \mathbb{W}$ in , the morphisms $\mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{W}$ are just the $\mathbb{F}$-linear maps $\mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{W}$. There are infinitely many morphisms if both (1) $\mathbb{V}$ and $\mathbb{W}$ have positive dimension and (2) either the field $\mathbb{F}$ is infinite or $\mathbb{V}$ or $\mathbb{W}$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: How do we know that there are infinitely many morphisms $Hom(A,B)$ given that those two properties hold?

Comment: Oh yes of course